# NSOutlineView scroll animation is not working

Tags: macos, animation, nsoutlineview

I want to remove the `NSOutlineView`'s show/hide button.So,I override the `NSOutlineView` and get the `mouseDown` event.The follow is the code.

```
    -(void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
    NSLog(@"LeftFolderListOutlineView mouseDown");
    [super mouseDown:theEvent];

    NSPoint localPoint = [self convertPoint:theEvent.locationInWindow
                                   fromView:nil];
    NSInteger row = [self rowAtPoint:localPoint];

    id clickedItem = [self itemAtRow:row];

    if (![clickedItem isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
        return;
    }


    if ([self isItemExpanded:clickedItem]) {

        [[self animator] collapseItem:clickedItem];

    }else{
        [[self animator] expandItem:clickedItem];
    }

}
```

It should be a scroll animation when the NSOutlineView collapse or expand.But in this case it's not working.Anyone tell me why and how can I improve this?

Answer (score 0):

To remove 'show/hide button' (outline cell) you could implement `- (NSRect)frameOfOutlineCellAtRow:(NSInteger)row` method in the NSOutliveView subclass and return NSZeroRect.

NSOutlineView collapse/expand animation is not animatable via `animator`.

Only OS 10.7 or above provide collapse/expand animation effects. So it you planed to support older OS versions you need to provide separate implementation.

If you want to provide collapse/expand animation on OS 10.6 or below, you definitely needed to override 'drawRect' of NSOutlineView.

-- Update --

Sorry, I think I neglected the main point. 10.7 expand/collapse animation is automatically kick in only when users clicked the outline cell. If we want to show the animation without  default outline cells, there is no other way but manually implementing animation effects, I think.

I made a sample project that implement expand/collapse animation effects with image drawing.
Check the source codes in here: https://github.com/roh0sun/ovanimation

Comment: But my system is os 10.7,I want to know how to let the animation work

Comment: I have read your code.I think your project can complete the image draw animation.But the expand/collapse animation is still not working.